# DevExpressGridView: How to select the first row after sorting it by descending order

Tags: c#, devexpress

Suppose you have a GridView(DevExpress), How do you select the first row after sorting?

```
gridView1.OptionsBehavior.KeepFocusedRowOnUpdate = false;
colCreatedDate.SortIndex = 0;
colCreatedDate.SortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Descending;
```

This thing doesn't work it only select the first row before the sorting happens.

```
gridView1.Columns.View.MoveFirst();
gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = 1;
gridView1.FocusedColumn = colCreatedDate;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize my problem now. Sort all the rows first after that call an event that select the first row after sorting the Gridview.

```
private void gridView1_EndSorting(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = 0;
}
```

[image]